# Algebra of dimensions of Subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\newcommand{\span}{\operatorname{span}}$Prove that the following is true for any subspaces $V, W$ of $\mathbb{F}_n$:

$$\dim(V + W) = \dim(V) + \dim(W) - \dim(V\cap W).$$

My attempt:

Let $V, W$ and $Z$ in $\mathbb{F}_n$ be given.

If $V\cap W=\{\mathcal{O}\},$ we have that $V\bigoplus W=V+W.$ Remark that $\dim(V\cap W)=\dim({\mathcal{O}})=0$ Thus, it follows that 
$\dim(V + W) = \dim(V) + \dim(W)= \dim(V) + \dim(W)- \dim(V\cap W)$.

If $V\cap W\neq\{\mathcal{O}\},$ let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for $V \cap W$. Enlarge $\mathcal{B}$ to a basis $\mathcal{C}$ of $V$, and enlarge $\mathcal{B}$ to a basis $\mathcal{D}$ of $W$. 
It suffices to show that $C \cup D$ is a basis of $V + W.$ Now, $V+W$ is the smallest subspace that contain both $V$ and $W.$ And $\span(\mathcal{C}\cup\mathcal{D})=\span(C)+\span(D)$ is also the samllest subspace that contain both $V$ and $W,$ consequently, $\span(\mathcal{C}\cup\mathcal{D})=V + W.$ We are left to show that $\mathcal{C}\cup\mathcal{D}$ is lineraly independent. Note that $\mathcal{C}\cup\mathcal{D}=\{c_1,c_2,\cdots, c_e, d_1, d_2, \cdots , d_f, u_1,u_2,\cdots, u_g\}$ for some $e,f,g\in \mathbb{R}$ where $c_i\in \mathcal{C}\cap \mathcal{D}^C, d_j\in \mathcal{D}\cap \mathcal{C}^C,$ and $u_j\in \mathcal{C}\cap \mathcal{D}.$ We wish to show that
$=\alpha_1 c_1 + \cdots +\alpha_{e+1} d_1+ \cdots +\alpha_{e+f+1} u_1 + \cdots = \mathcal{O}
$
only holds when $\alpha_i=0.$

End.

How should I proceed to show that the vectors are independent. It is intuitively true but I just cannot get it.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You covered the case $V \cap W = \{0\}$.

**Hint:** For a different approach in case $V \cap W \neq \{0\}$.

$$A : V \times W \to V + W$$ where $A (v,w) = v + w$ for $v \in V$ and $ w \in W$ is surjective. And its kernel is given by $$\ker (A) = \{ (u,-u); u \in V \cap W\}$$

Notice that the correspondence $u \mapsto (u,-u)$ is an isomorphism between $V \cap W$ and $\ker (A)$.

Now use the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rank-NullityTheorem.html).

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions.